# Need to get the Safari's password through code using SecKeychainFindGenericPassword

Tags: macos, safari, osx-mavericks, keychain

When I use SecKeychainFindGenericPassword for other applications in the keychain, my code returns the password properly, but when I try to get Safari's password, it returns an error code. How do I get the Safari's application password using SecKeychainFindGenericPassword?

Answer (score 0):

To read a Keychain password using SecKeychainFindGenericPassword API, the account name should be the value it displays against Account and serviceName should be the value it displays for Where when you select the password item in Keychain Access application.

Eg: To read password stored in Safari Extensions List, the account is "Safari" and the service name is "Extended Preferences"